# Prevent scroll bar from not moving at the top

Tags: magento2, javascript

How can i prevent my scroll bar to not move at the top on click event.
Visit https://wazoodle01.wsisites.net/knowledge-base/order-information/wholesale-faq.html# and click on any option listed below.You will see the scroll bar goes to the top. How to prevent that.
here is my code .

```
 `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.faq-main-content').hide();jQuery('.faq-main-content.faq-content').hide();
jQuery(".faq-content-header").delegate('a','click',function(e){
    if(jQuery(e.target).data('link')!=='redirect'){
        jQuery(e.target).toggleClass('question_minus').parent().next('.faq-content').slideToggle();e.preventDefault();
        }});
        jQuery(".faq-header").delegate('a','click',function(e){
            jQuery(e.target).toggleClass('section_minus').parent().next('.faq-main-content').slideToggle();
            if((jQuery(e.target).parent().next('.faq-main-content').children('.faq-content').is(':visible'))){
                jQuery(e.target).parent().next('.faq-main-content').children('.faq-content').slideUp();
                if(jQuery(e.target).parent().next('.faq-main-content').children('.faq-content-header').children('a').is(".question_minus")){
                    jQuery(e.target).parent().next('.faq-main-content').children('.faq-content-header').children('a').removeClass('question_minus');
                    }}

e.preventDefault();
 })});</script>`
```

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you have `href="#"`, your options are to remove `href="#"` (valid HTML5) or add the below javascript inside your click event:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I have already added preventDefault()

Comment: You should move it higher up so it's the first line inside the click event. Or remove the href.

Comment: I would also recommend using `.on` rather than `delegate`

> .delegate() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method since jQuery 1.7

Comment: check this https://wazoodle01.wsisites.net/knowledge-base/orders-faq.html#  click on any option below. see what happens. On clicking twice the event is triggered

Comment: Yes, if you remove the href it no longer occurs. Or even better, change the element so it is no longer an `<a>` tag. If you aren't linking anywhere it doesn't make sense to be an anchor element.